# Which form between solar panel and wind turbines requires less cost in servicing?

Tags: solar-energy, alternator, windturbine

I found that the average life of a solar panel is about 25 years and that of the the wind turbine is also somewhat close to 25 years.
But the wind turbines require alternator in order to generate electricity which is showing an average life span of 7 years.
One factor does add up to the cost of solar panels which is the cost to clean the panels in order to keep it dust free.
Even after adding that cost to the solar panels it appears that it must be requiring very  less cost in servicing.

I did some research but no proper information was available that after a 7 year time span of the alternator the whole alternator need to be changed or just some parts of it as this will vary the cost of servicing prominently.

If anyone in this community have any information regarding the above mentioned field please share it.

Comment: You are probably right : mechanical moving parts are likely to require more servicing. Not just alternator, but furling mechanisms, brakes, etc.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I agree, but then economics kick in: What's the sweet spot for price and life time  (in €/MWh of energy produce in lifetime) for the DC/AC conversion in solar parks? Do they get designed for the same life time as wind parks? Or are they intentionally designed to be cheaper because chances are, x years from installation, it pays to upgrade / replace e.g. the cells themselves to utilize efficiency gains and get rid of efficiency degradation due to aging optics/coatings?

Comment: Also, when having 1000 inverters with all their own failure probabilities, are you really servicing less than having 1 large wind turbine with the same cumulative power? Do we have to factor in the maintenance effort for the energy storage necessary to make daytime-only production of power useful at all? And, seeing that this probably means mostly pumped storage hydropower plants: what's cheaper to maintain: the big wind turbine or the (slightly) smaller water turbine and pumps?

Comment: It seems likely that there will be a lot of variation related to location. Also looking at historical data you may find recent reduced use of some technology because service costs. Looking into the future you might expect some emerging approaches to prove more reliable. In wind turbines, gear speed reducers that have been unreliable in the past have been improved or replaced with direct-drive generator technologies. In thermal and hydro plants generators have lasted many decades, exceeding a century with rewinding and other maintenance rather than replacement.

Comment: @MarcusMüller These are very different questions. I'd expect a DC bus to a big (MW class) inverter or even a HVDC link. Like the huts dotted around this piece of art... https://scontent.flhr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/87947319_10216214869780524_6707452242934366208_o.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_sid=8024bb&_nc_ohc=rsmXpl4lw7gAX8cH3iN&_nc_ht=scontent.flhr6-1.fna&oh=ef0689c866680f0f02f60cb32dcf48df&oe=5F72DFF3

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'll agree that "how much does it cost to maintain a wind turbine for 25 years, and how much a solar panel" is a different question. But the context of "... for a large scale power demand" is kind of important here. Regarding the art: WOW.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ... I call it the Solar Challenge, and nominate the USA to beat it. 
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10216214869740523&set=pb.1115627641.-2207520000..&type=3&theater

Comment: @BrianDrummond :D also, the fact that it's a massive power plant somewhere in the desert in not-exactly-densely-populated Inner Mongolia definitely explains the HVDC (albeit: [maybe it's all just for local mining of bitcoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalad_Banner#Economy)). Don't think the smaller patches of solar panels you see in southern Germany along motorways very occasionally will try to couple to some DC bus.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Actually zoom out a bit and it's a fraction of the plant, and it's next to a big city. Zoom out a little more and it disappears altogether, the low res satellite pass is a bit older than the high res pass. Which gives some idea of the rate of development. (Google Earth) But they are building big HVDC links too.

Comment: yeah, the metropolitan area there has a population of 2e6, so I might need to correct my statement.

Answer (score -4):

Brushless alternators most commonly fail due to 1 of the 6 diodes in the 3 phase bridge from overtemp that may be improved with better cooling.  The peak currents are much higher than the RMS . The battery ESR can be <5 mOhms so the diodes need to be lower at rated current.

Comment: You have not answered the OP;s question but just provided meaningless facts.

Comment: Tony, I know you're quite a bit more experienced than I am, and knowledge just flows from you, but can you try to really be sure that you're addressing the question with your answers?